# jQuery UI "Loading..." Error Processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, client-side

Dear all I am using jQuery Grid to display data for user administration. When I click on '+' sign, I get a Dialog box that pops up, wherein I can create a new user. I use a server-side call to populate cascading lists.

When I submit the request: On failure, or even on success, the 'Loading...' button never seems to disappear. I fear that I am leaving some resource open, or worse. As I am inheriting this application, and have no jQuery experience whatsoever, I was hoping you could help me. I apologize in advance if this is something really simple; but, I could not find anything on the Web that help me resolve this issue.

I am using Struts 2 along with jQuery; however, I don't think we use the jQuery Struts 2 plugin. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/fragments/directive.jsp" %>  

<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
<div class="error">
    <s:actionerror/>
</div>
</s:if>
<s:form action="userAdminCreateSubmit" namespace="/ti/tmsportal/ga" onsubmit="return false;" >
<s:textfield key="user.username" required="true" />
<s:textfield key="user.firstName" required="true" />
<s:textfield key="user.middleInitial" />
<s:textfield key="user.lastName" required="true" />
<s:textfield key="user.email" required="true" />
<s:textfield key="user.phone" required="true" />            
<s:select key="user.organizationId" list="organizations" listKey="value" listValue="label" required="true" onchange="changeWorkgroups(this.value);changeRoles(this.value);" />
<s:select key="user.workgroupId" list="workgroups" listKey="value" listValue="label" onchange="changeLocations(this.value);" />
<s:select key="user.locationId" list="locations" listKey="value" listValue="label" />
<s:select key="user.portalRole" list="roles" listKey="value" listValue="label" emptyOption="true" required="true" onchange="changeLevels(this.value);" />
<s:select key="user.levelCode" list="levels" listKey="value" listValue="label" emptyOption="true" required="true" />

</s:form>   

<s:url action="lookup" var="workgroupLookupUrl" >
<s:param name="type">workgroupsInOrganization</s:param>
</s:url>

<s:url action="lookup" var="locationLookupUrl" >
<s:param name="type">locationsInWorkgroup</s:param>
</s:url>

<s:url action="lookup" var="roleLookupUrl" >
<s:param name="type">rolesForOrg</s:param>
</s:url>

<s:url action="lookup" var="levelLookupUrl" >
<s:param name="type">levelsForRole</s:param>
</s:url>


<script>
function changeWorkgroups(key)
{
    $('#userAdminCreateSubmit [name="user.workgroupId"]').load('<s:property value="#workgroupLookupUrl" />&key=' + key + ' option',
        function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            changeLocations();
            setVisibility();
        }
    );      
}

function changeLocations(key)
{
    $('#userAdminCreateSubmit [name="user.locationId"]').load('<s:property value="#locationLookupUrl" />&key=' + key + ' option',
        function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            setVisibility();
        }
    );
}

function changeRoles(key)
{
    $('#userAdminCreateSubmit [name="user.portalRole"]').load('<s:property value="#roleLookupUrl" />&key=' + key + ' option',
        function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            changeLevels($('#userAdminCreateSubmit [name="user.portalRole"]').value());
        });
}

function changeLevels(key)
{
    $('#userAdminCreateSubmit [name="user.levelCode"]').load('<s:property value="#levelLookupUrl" />&key=' + key + ' option');
}   

function setVisibility()
{
    $('#userAdminCreateSubmit [name="user.workgroupId"]').parents('tr').toggle(
        $('#userAdminCreateSubmit [name="user.workgroupId"] option[value!=""]').size() > 0
    );

    $('#userAdminCreateSubmit [name="user.locationId"]').parents('tr').toggle(
        $('#userAdminCreateSubmit [name="user.locationId"] option[value!=""]').size() > 0
    );
}

$(function()
{
    $('.button').button();
    setVisibility();
    addFieldHint('user.receiveNotifications', '<s:text name="content.help.receiveNotifications" />');       
    addFieldHint('user.username', '<s:text name="content.help.username" />');
});

function submitUserAdminCreate()
{
    $.post('<s:url action="userAdminCreateSubmit" namespace="/ti/tmsportal/ga" />', $('#userAdminCreateSubmit').serialize(),
        function(data) {
            $('#userAdminDialog').empty().append(data);
        }
    );
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have any JS error messages displayed? If you use Firefox and view the console / error log.

Comment: Dear Alex: I get the following response on the Web Console on FireFox: [16:54:38.272] $("#userAdminCreateSubmit [name=\"user.portalRole\"]").value is not a function @ http://localhost:9080/portal/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js:26.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your JS error, just change

```
$('#userAdminCreateSubmit [name="user.portalRole"]').value()
```

to

```
$('#userAdminCreateSubmit [name="user.portalRole"]').val()
```